# The numerical stability of orient operation of three points in a plain

Tags: decimal-point, numerical-stability

The following photo is a part of a paper(Quicker than Quickhull by Nam-Du ̃ng Hoang et al) and it is about the orient operator of three points in a plain that uses the cross-product.

[image]

It is said that the numerical stability of (4) is worse than (2) and (3), in general.
From the resources found on the Internet, I can expect as it is said, but I do not know why it is exactly.

Decimal point operation is not very accurate when it comes to computation by computers. Could anyone please explain (or compare the (2)~(4) equations) what exactly happens in terms of numerical stability?

Comment: Are you asking about how much error each floating point operation can potentially introduce?

Comment: @apokryfos I think that also can be answered to the question.